# Inequality for the gradient of a power of absolute value

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open, and let $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a smooth complex-valued function which does not vanish anywhere on $U$.  Let $r > 0$ be a real constant.

> Does the inequality $$\left| \nabla (|f|^r) \right| \le r |f|^{r-1} |\nabla f|$$
>   hold pointwise?  Is there a nice elegant proof?

For $f > 0$ the inequality is an equality, since $\nabla (f^r) = r f^{r-1} \nabla f$ by the chain rule.  If we identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ and take $f$ holomorphic, it is not hard to show that $\left| \nabla (|f|^r) \right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} r |f|^{r-1} |\nabla f|$ so the inequality can be strict.

For the general case, I am getting bogged down in real and imaginary parts - there must be a better way.

If there is a proof that works for $\mathbb{R}^d$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is even better.

---

Notation, as requested: $\nabla f : U \to \mathbb{C}^2$ is, as usual, the function $\nabla f = ( \partial_x f, \partial_y f)$.  The partial derivatives $\partial_x f, \partial_y f$ are defined by taking the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts of $f$ separately. So if $f = u+iv$ where $u,v  : U \to \mathbb{R}$ are the real and imaginary parts, we have $\partial_x f = \partial_x u + i \partial_x v$, etc.  In particular, we have
$$|\nabla f| = \sqrt{(\partial_x u)^2 + (\partial_y u)^2 + (\partial_x v)^2 + (\partial_y v)^2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $|f|^r$ as $(f \bar f)^{r/2}$.  Then by the chain rule and the product rule (valid for complex-valued functions),
$$\begin{align*}
\partial_x |f|^r &= \partial_x (f \bar f)^{r/2} \\
&= \frac{r}{2} (f \bar f)^{\frac{r}{2}-1}(\bar{f} \partial_x f + f \partial_x \bar f) \\
&= \frac{r}{2} |f|^{r-2} (\bar f \partial_x f  + f \overline{\partial_x  f} ) \\
&= r |f|^{r-2} \operatorname{Re}(f \partial_x f).\end{align*}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align*} \left| \left(\partial_x |f|^r\right) \right| \le r |f|^{r-2} |f \partial_x f| = r |f|^{r-1} |\partial_x f|.\end{align*}$$
Doing the same for $\partial_y$ and summing the squares gives
$$\begin{align*}|\nabla (|f|^r)|^2 &= \left| \left(\partial_x |f|^r\right) \right|^2  + \left| \left(\partial_y |f|^r\right) \right|^2 \\ &\le r^2 |f|^{2r-2} (|\partial_x f|^2 + |\partial_y f|^2)\\ &= r^2 |f|^{2r-2} |\nabla f|^2 \end{align*}$$
which is the square of the desired inequality.  This immediately generalizes to any number of variables.